# Will I lose my data on an ongoing game if I quit?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Will I lose my data on an ongoing game that is still in progress if I quit it?

What happened was, I had accidentaly glitched S.A.M. and while playing none of the missiles attacked me and I just kept on going but know I want to stop it so if I quit it will I lose all that progress? Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you quit you will lose that progress.